# git nothing to commit working directory clean

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

my git remote origin is my working directory, and my git remote 'upstream' is a project on which my development based. when i use

```
git pull upstream master
```

I can see that i've got the latest changes in the upstream directory, and I use

```
git add --all
```

`git` gives out some insertions, some deletions which are all right.

But when I use:

```
git commit -m "..."
```

I always get this error

```
nothing to commit working directory clean
```

and

```
git push origin master
```

git says

```
already up to date
```

I check my origin directory and find it does not contains the latest updates in upstream directory

I've seen the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067873/git-nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean). He says he encountered this problem because he enters a wrong direcotory but i'm sure i 'm in the right directory.

I asked someone, he used

```
git log
```

to find out my newest commit serial number and used some commands like
`git merge (commit serial number)` which solve my problem but I forgot the exact command he used.

He explained that the HEAD pointer points to another position which is different from my newest commit but i didn't quite understand at that time.
I'm not familiar with git, can somebody explains why this happens and how to solve this problem? (Like I said, I forgot the exact command he used and I encountered the same problem now and I don't know how to solve it)

Answer (score 1):

After fetching from the remote branch, you would still have to merge the commits.

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master master
git rebase upstream/master
```